# Xamarin Form Exception Heaps size and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How can I enable large heap in my Xamarin.Forms application ?

Here is `MainActivity.cs` Android code:

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        RoundedBoxViewRenderer.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

See Exception Screenshot below:

[image: Exception Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Go to project Options > Android Build > General > Enable MultiDex & Options > Android Build > Advacnced > JavaHeapSize (Set **3G**) , In manifest file you can add **android:largeHeap="true"** in Application Tag

```
<application android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

Comment: how can i get these option in VS2013

Comment: Go to Solution Explorer , Right Click on the Android Project eg. MyProject.Droid in Popup  select Properties/Option then follow the above

Comment: Before you enable largeHeap you should try to find out what causes the OutOfMemoryException and fix that. In most if not all cases are memory leaks the root of all that eval. Go use the Xamarin Profiler and Android Studios memory monitor to profile your apps memory usage.

Comment: we have set heapsize to 3G , but unable to find manifest file for add tag. where is it ? - imrohit

Comment: We have got the manifest file and added tag as you type above,  OutOfMemoryException still there its crashes the app when we load images from URLs.

Comment: @ZuhaibShah OutOfMemoryError may not be due to insufficient heap.Can you show more detail about your code.

Answer (score 1):

The Xamarin way of setting the Dalvik/Art large heap via the `Appication` attribute:

### Application.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace LargeHeap
{
    [Application(LargeHeap = true)]
    public class XamarinApplication : Application
    {
        public XamarinApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

> If true, then the process should be created with a large Dalvik heap; otherwise, the process will be created with the default Dalvik heap.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.ApplicationAttribute.LargeHeap/

Answer (score 0):

My contribution, it worked for me:

**[assembly: Application(LargeHeap = true)]**

```
namespace Project.Droid
{
    [Activity(.............)]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

    }
}
```